# Why does it always echo the "Not set!" though I enter data?

Tags: php

Though I enter data and hit `Submit` it always echoes the `else` part always. I know it isn't the type of question to be asked on Stackoverflow but...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sticky Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>>
            <label for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="FName">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php 

            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $f_name = $_POST['FName'];
                echo "$f_name";
            }

            else 
            {
                echo "Not set!";
            }
         ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
 <input type="submit">
```

to

```
 <input type="submit"  name="submit">
```

P.S: key name in global arrays comes from users input ($POST,$_GET,$_COOKIE), if you want to change its key, you need to change that element's name!